# Why should I do review queues?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, badges

When I got 2000 points, I got these *Review queues* in the right top corner with a number of available reviews.

Is it my responsibility now? Should I do them? Or is it completely voluntary?

If I do, what does it give me back? Which advantages?

Comment: You _should_ do them. You don't _need_ to, but nobody's going to get mad at you for doing reviews, unless you do them badly. (and by "badly", I mean robo-reviewing -- just constantly clicking "Looks OK"/"Accept" to get the badge, rather than actually reviewing. Messing up every now and then is fine, though you might be forced to take a day or two off from reviewing if you happen to fail too many audits in too little time.)

Comment: Seriously now, if you don't want to do them that's OK. It's the same as for answering questions: nobody is forcing you to; you do it mainly because it makes you feel good, helping people. And if you think you can't help doing reviews, if you're not good at it, that's fine too. You can't be good at everything, so you won't also, for instance, be participating in tags you know nothing about. That is just natural and expected.

Comment: Amazon Mechanical Turk and working through review queues have more in common than one might think. If you enjoy the former even without getting paid, you might like the later.

Comment: You can earn several times the [**Steward**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) gold badge.

Comment: @le_m, what is Amazon Mechanical Turk?

Comment: @Alex https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk - crowd sourcing tasks which computers cannot solve, uses many validation techniques also implemented on SO; main differences are: SO review tasks partially require expert domain knowledge and MTurk pays up to a few cents per completed task.

Comment: Pardon the last comment. I was going to just replace the link with one for the correct review queue but I don't think there is a FAQ for reviewing edits.

Comment: If you want to hate yourself and/or humanity more than you currently do, and/or lose faith in humanity, do review queues.

Comment: You should get the "Review queues" button in the top right corner from 500+ rep already.

Comment: @Ivar, maybe I had, but didn't pay attention, probably there were no numbers there.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

> Or it's completely voluntary?

Correct.

> If I do, what does it give me back? Which advantages?

A cleaner site, where you can find good stuff easier as there is less cruft and bad stuff.

Also, there are the following badges for reviewing:

1. [Proofreader](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1276/proofreader)
2. [Custodian](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian)
3. [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer)
4. [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward)

Comment: ... and these gold badges should be repeating, to encourage the voluntary. (Just loud thinking while looking at the close votes). I mean realy, what is a gold badge for 16 hours of work (assuming 1 minute per review)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I want reviewers to review because they care about the quality of content on this site, not because they want badges. The badges are good for getting people into reviewing, but they are also really good at attracting robo-reviewers who just want to get the badge and don't care at all about the quality of content on this site. I personally don't care about badges other than tag badges. I mean, I get excited every time I get a new one, but I don't go looking for a badge before performing a task, nor do I hinge my participation on potential badges that I may earn from doing so

Comment: @TinyGiant we even not getting the first statistic page up to 40 reviews for each listed person, hence the big queue. Badges are an motivation for many people here.

Comment: I want to be a good reviewer that cares about the quality of the content on this site AND get cool badges.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Badges tend to be a large motivation for people doing a very poor job.  It's typically irrelevant to almost all reviewers who are doing a good job.

Comment: @Servy these users should be caught by the audit system. Close Votes [seems to be to unatractive for most of users](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) (less then 20 person with all 40 review actions). That was all I wanted to point out. My comment was not "give me badge" (This was bad communicated from my part). It was more meant as: "How about more badges, that would increase the motivation of other users to review"

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Ideally, sure, audits would catch all bad reviewers.  In reality, they help a bit, getting rid of some of the worst of the worst, but they still let through *lots* and *lots* of quite poor reviewers.  Adding more badges would likely increase the number of bad reviewers (as more bad reviewers would come seeking badges); it wouldn't increase the number of good reviewers (because those people are already reviewing, and aren't incentivised by the badge even if they're not).

Comment: Those who care about the quality of the site would rather work with raising opinion on meta about better alternatives than having 42 different review queues for everything. As we can learn from the past, the amount of crap that needs review does not scale with the amount of users that can and will review. Therefore the queues just grow. Those who work with programming might know that queues are just a solution to handle _peaks_ in data traffic. If your program is always too slow to process everything and deplete the queue, no amount of queues will save it - it will run out of memory and crash.

Comment: I have personally stopped reviewing because I don't believe it is a viable long-term solution to ensure quality. In fact, the quality of the content of SO has dropped significantly over the past 5 years, while the amount of available review queues have increased. The only kind of review that would make sense is to review all first-time/low rep questions _before_ the question is allowed to become visible on the site. If we don't have enough reviewers for that, then reviewing is probably a doomed method. Smarter scripts to detect and block crappy questions might be the way to go instead.

Comment: Badges are a nontrivial motivation for me and many other high quality reviewers. I wish people would stop spreading the false notion that only robo reviewers and crappy users care about badges.

Comment: Speaking candidly: I think that this view is naive. Most people are motivated by status > cleaner community. Even the outliers have their limits on what they're willing to spend valuable time on, unrewarded. Status is at the heart of the entire reputation system, and is the reason that it succeeds. Try removing that system and see what happens to the volume of quality new answers-- probably the same thing that's *presently* happening with the overcrowded review queues. I acknowledge there'd need to be greater prevention of low-quality reviewers, but that's a poor excuse to remain stagnant.

Answer (score 15):

> ... what does it give me back? Which advantages?

#### Moderator elections

The <kbd>Reviewer</kbd> and <kbd>Steward</kbd> badges related to these statistics in those review queues seem to be taken into account (only once ...) to calculate the [Candidate Score](https://data.stackexchange.com/drupal/query/298418/candidate-score), which are used as some sort of indicator for participants in **moderator elections** I believe (while the <kbd>Custodian</kbd> badge seems to be ignored for that).

These review queues statistics may also help to decide about nominees for [Moderators Pro Tempore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) on beta sites.

#### Help new users

Another advantage of such reviews is that in the first / late review queues you often see posts from brand new users, which gives you a chance to help them to get going if you see any of the typical mistakes from new users (more or less around the time the mistake happens) ... If that's what you like doing of course, e.g via whatever kind of constructive comments to challenge them to improve their posts.

Comment: My perception, as someone who's never actually been a moderator, is that moderation is a horrible, thankless job where you get yelled at and scrutinized for your every decision with little or no reward.  In other words, "Well, sure, the flu's unpleasant, but if you just keep getting yourself sick, eventually you could *die of dysentery*.  Wouldn't that be awesome?"

Comment: @Kevin what doesn't kill you only makes you stronger and all that? :p

Comment: Nah @Kevin, we do have some fun behind the scenes. :o)

Comment: @BhargavRao any idea why my answer attrackts so much (66% right now ...) comments from ... euh ... mods? Did I write anything wrong? Need I rework my answer (hopfeully not delete it ...)? Should I add a real world sample of how "I" use such stats to know (for myself) that what somebody wrote on some other site (about participating in review ueueus) is NOT true?

Comment: Nopes Pierre, the comments are for Kevin, who told that the job which we are doing is "a thankless job". Your answer is quite great.

Comment: @Kevin Hey, [The Oregon Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Oregon_Trail_(video_game)) made dying of dysentery fun (it was hunting animals by typing complex words that was horrible). Moderation is just about as fun

Answer (score 7):

I think @Oded's point about keeping the site "clean" is a major reason behind it.

Take a look at how many questions there are in the top tags (e.g. C#, Java) at peak hours - as I write this, it's almost 11:30 at night in the Midwestern U.S. and 12:30 AM on the East Coast (hardly peak hours), and yet some Java questions that were written a little over half an hour ago are no longer on the first page. The fact is, given the question volume on Stack Overflow, it's not necessarily all that easy to get attention for even a well-written question; this problem would be much worse if bad questions weren't being removed.

Even if individual review efforts don't seem to make *that* much of a difference, keep in mind that there's a strong [broken windows effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) that amplifies both community policing efforts and a lack thereof, so it can make more of a difference than you'd initially think. Quite simply, bad questions attract more bad questions if they're not addressed promptly - same for bad answers, actually.

Comment: "Broken windows theory", being a potential civil rights issue, may not be a very good motivation for many.

Comment: @farhanjk: Why is it a potential civil rights issue (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: "The theory suggests that policing methods that target minor crimes, such as vandalism, loitering, public drinking, jaywalking and fare evasion, help to create an atmosphere of order and lawfulness, thereby preventing more serious crimes." - Wikipedia.

- More policing of thought in the context of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

If reputation is what you're really interested in, instead of just badges and altruism (which are more or less what existing answers are primarily describing), I have found that the queues are a pretty good place to find new questions that need decent answers. It's probably not the most efficient way to find such questions, but it's not bad either.

Additionally, if you're the kind of person who just likes to surf around on Stack Overflow, like I am, it provides a little bit more of a richer experience when puttering around for a few minutes.